# Can the TinyMCE5 toolbar be hidden while maintaining toolbar plugins?

Tags: tinymce

I have a document editor that has an edit and readonly mode. The readonly mode is a static renderer that just uses HTML/CSS and the edit mode initializes a tinyMCE edtior. However I'm adding a track changes plugin that requires tinyMCE to be active in readonly and edit mode. My plan is to have tinyMCE active at all times but modify the toggle to switch between a readonly and edit state. The native tinyMCE methods for this don't seem to satisfy what I'm trying to do so this is my plan:

- I used `editor.setMode('readonly')` and it makes the toolbar inaccessible but still visible and the document itself is still editable. Setting via DOM manipulation `contenteditable="false"` makes the document uneditable but it seems hacky, is there an editor method that would do this for me?
- I can also just hide the toolbar using DOM manipulations but it also seemed hacky so I'm asking if there is a way to do this through some editor method without actually turning off any of the active plugins at the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the toolbar by setting the `toolbar` value in the configuration to `false`.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#disablingthetoolbar

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: "#theEditor",
   toolbar: false,
   ...
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to destroy the old editor and instantiate a new editor? My goal is to keep one editor and manipulate the state so that the toolbar display can be toggled.

Comment: Ah - once the editor is on the page you cannot remove the toolbar.  TinyMCE (at present) does not support doing that.  I would request that feature via the GitHub Issue Tracker for TinyMCE:  https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues

Comment: Ah I see, good to know that I'm not just hacking together something that it already supports.